# Why does JavaScript null evaluate strangely?

Tags: javascript

Why was JavaScript null made the way it is?

Consider this example:

```
null == 0 // false
null >= 0 // true
null > 0  // false
```

Comment: All the answers here: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/

Comment: "Why" is a really BIG question.  One thing to keep in mind is that JavaScript is "loosely typed" which means a lot of really weird things work (or at least seem to work).  The above links should give you some good reading though.